# error when downloading file using document.location.href

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webpage that uses a

```
document.location.href
```

to redirect the user to a new controller that return a file:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string BillRef)
        {return new DownloadFileActionResult(SessionManager.DataToDownload, SessionManager.DataNameToDownload, ExportFileType.CSV);}
```

but it doesn't work and the application returns to the login page.

There is no exception (neither in Application_Error from Global.asax).

I have tested putting the url in a popup instead of the document.location.href, and it works, the file is downloading:

```
window.open(urlRedirect);
```

I want to keep the file download in the current tab and not use a popup. Do you have an idea how can I do that?

Comment: plz post the controller action code here..

Comment: @Exception: return new DownloadFileActionResult(SessionManager.DataToDownload, SessionManager.DataNameToDownload, ExportFileType.CSV); is the only line you need :-) The conteoller is not called with the document.location.href (I put a breakpoint but he's not hitten)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using

```
document.location
```

try using

```
window.location = urlRedirect;
```

note, that some file types will be shown in line than offered as a download, that's a browser thing, not much you can do on the client side about that.

Comment: Thanks, but there is the same problem! it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly but I don't know why the old one workn't:

```
window.location.href
```